# android - Checkbox with 2 lines and different font

Tags: android, checkbox

How can I create checkbox with 2 lines, where every line has different font size and color?
Such like that:
[image]

Comment: Do you want this to be a list item? You can always make a custom view with two `TextView`s and a `CheckBox` element positioned the way you want inside a `RelativeLayout`

Comment: Those are very likely three different views 1: a caption less checkbox, 2: a larger font TextView, 3: a smaller font TextView.

Comment: BVB-can you please give example how to do it

Comment: MazeHatter-I can do it in your way but since this is the first picture that exist in Android developer site under checkbox page I believe this is a pure checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Dude use advanced checkbox with layout inflater. In Android, if you don't like an item you can customise it with custom class and custom layout. .